# Have a consumer listening to multiple queues, but it should consume all messages from queue A before queue B

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, node-amqplib

I'm new to RabbitMQ and I'm still learning how it works. So far I managed to create two pieces of code (using the `amqplib` package for Node.js): a publisher that sends messages to queue A and queue B; and a consumer that consumes the messages from queue A and queue B.

However, queue A should have a higher priority than queue B so I would like to create my consumer in a way that it will listen to both queue A and queue B, but it will consume all the messages from queue A first, and only after queue A is empty it will consume the messages in queue B.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Priority queue ?

Comment: An example how that can be done would be helpful.